# For elements with box-sizing: border-box, only absolute content area dimensions can be applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I added two images to my html page and they're large in size. I attached a screenshot of images for reference. [images_full_size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOEuU.jpg) I added a dive with a class of thumbnail using bootstrap. Images got smaller and fitted to the Grid. I am unable to change the height of the first image. I attached second image for reference. [img with thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jH3NB.png) I tried to change the height through chrome inspector to be the same height as second image but I got an error saying "For elements with box-sizing: border-box, only absolute content area dimensions can be applied" [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HB3yM.jpg) Pleas can you help how can I solve this.
Thank you.

My code is

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Grid Basics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/JoH60FhTp50">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/buF62ewDLcQ">
      </div>    
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Because I can't seem to reproduce the error in Chromium.

Comment: Hi Mr Lister. Sure. Please find my code above. I have edited it. Thank you.